# Can I ask if my calculation is correct?

Tags: discussion, homework-and-exercises

Let's say I've been working in a calculation which is *reasonable simple* but I didn't found it done anywhere else. Can I post is in physics.SE and ask what the community think about it?

I know in other SE communities that would not be allowed but in physics that might be, because checking whether the reasoning behind a calculation is correct is the core of the physicist work.

Comment: We welcome discussions like this [in the chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar) but not on the main site.

Comment: @JohnRennie are you talking about this actual question or the question in my question?

Comment: @JohnRennie I actually checked for this question but I guess I wasn't using the right words, sorry about that. It's certainly a duplicate.

Comment: I think John was talking about asking someone to check your work. That would be on topic in the chat room but generally not on the main site. (Chat has fairly loose standards about what is considered on topic there, unlike the main site.)